# htaccess | RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am migrating a web site from a Windows Server into a Apache and I like to redict some 404 URLs to correct/equivalent URL in my new server.

What I like to do is to make the following sorten by using RexEx:

```
Redirect 301 /username/search.asp                /newdir/username/
Redirect 301 /username/contact.asp               /newdir/username/
Redirect 301 /username/legalmarketing.asp        /newdir/username/
Redirect 301 /username/home.asp                  /newdir/username/
```

I have try to use the RewriteRule with something like that:

```
RewriteRule ^/username/(search|contact|legalmarketing|home)\.asp$ /newdir/username/ [R=301,L]
```

Bat this is not working. Any better idea please ? Am I doing something wrong ?

**UPDATE #1**

I also have try the

```
RewriteRule ^/username/search.asp$   /newdir/useranme/ [R=301,L]
#as well the following
RewriteRule ^username/search.asp$   /newdir/useranme/ [R=301,L]
```

but still no chance

**UPDATE #2**

I also have try this tutorial : http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html and the problem seems to be more complex, due to null values that I am getting from the server.

This is the code produced by the tutorial code:

```
Missed These Variables:
Array
(
    [INFO_API_VERSION] => (null)
    [INFO_AUTH_TYPE] => (null)
    [INFO_CONTENT_LENGTH] => (null)
    [INFO_CONTENT_TYPE] => (null)
    [INFO_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => (null)
    [INFO_GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTPS] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_ACCEPT] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_CONNECTION] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_COOKIE] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_FORWARDED] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_HOST] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_KEEP_ALIVE] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_MOD_SECURITY_MESSAGE] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_REFERER] => (null)
    [INFO_HTTP_USER_AGENT] => (null)
    [INFO_IS_SUBREQ] => (null)
    [INFO_ORIG_PATH_INFO] => (null)
    [INFO_ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED] => (null)
    [INFO_ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME] => (null)
    [INFO_ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME] => (null)
    [INFO_PATH] => (null)
    [INFO_PATH_INFO] => (null)
    [INFO_PHP_SELF] => (null)
    [INFO_QUERY_STRING] => (null)
    [INFO_REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => (null)
    [INFO_REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER] => (null)
    [INFO_REDIRECT_STATUS] => (null)
    [INFO_REDIRECT_URL] => (null)
    [INFO_REMOTE_ADDR] => (null)
    [INFO_REMOTE_HOST] => (null)
    [INFO_REMOTE_IDENT] => (null)
    [INFO_REMOTE_PORT] => (null)
    [INFO_REMOTE_USER] => (null)
    [INFO_REQUEST_FILENAME] => (null)
    [INFO_REQUEST_METHOD] => (null)
    [INFO_REQUEST_TIME] => (null)
    [INFO_REQUEST_URI] => (null)
    [INFO_SCRIPT_FILENAME] => (null)
    [INFO_SCRIPT_GROUP] => (null)
    [INFO_SCRIPT_NAME] => (null)
    [INFO_SCRIPT_URI] => (null)
    [INFO_SCRIPT_URL] => (null)
    [INFO_SCRIPT_USER] => (null)
    [INFO_SERVER_ADDR] => (null)
    [INFO_SERVER_ADMIN] => (null)
    [INFO_SERVER_NAME] => (null)
    [INFO_SERVER_PORT] => (null)
    [INFO_SERVER_PROTOCOL] => (null)
    [INFO_SERVER_SIGNATURE] => (null)
    [INFO_SERVER_SOFTWARE] => (null)
    [INFO_THE_REQUEST] => (null)
    [INFO_TIME] => (null)
    [INFO_TIME_DAY] => (null)
    [INFO_TIME_HOUR] => (null)
    [INFO_TIME_MIN] => (null)
    [INFO_TIME_MON] => (null)
    [INFO_TIME_SEC] => (null)
    [INFO_TIME_WDAY] => (null)
    [INFO_TIME_YEAR] => (null)
    [INFO_TZ] => (null)
    [INFO_UNIQUE_ID] => (null)
)
```

Any further idea please ?

Comment: Depending on where this code is located on your server, you might have to drop the leading slash `/` from your search pattern, or even set the `RewriteBase`.

Comment: The .htaccess file is located in the root directory of my web site, as well the RewriteBase is set to /

Comment: And removing the leading slash does nothing?

Comment: Yes, still does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below

```
RewriteRule ^username/search.asp$   http://www.yourdomainname.com/newdir/useranme/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for as well not solving my issue. What I like to do, is to use an or operator in regex in order to get any of the matched file names as I describe on the example

Comment: All i wanted to tell you is add your domain name to the new URL lilke `RewriteRule ^username/(search|contact|legalmarketing|home)\.asp$ http://www.yourdomainname.com/newdir/username/ [R=301,L]`